# How to locate the match node text in a linked XML database using XSLT1?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I know that my XML file format is not good but it is what it is. And I am limited to XSLT-1.

Here is some XSLK script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
      doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
      doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

    <xsl:variable name="EnglishDB" select="document('MWBData_ENG.XML')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="PunjabiDB" select="document('MWBData_PAN.XML')"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <title>Terminology List</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select ="$EnglishDB/MeetingWorkBook/*/WatchtowerStudyTheme"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select ="$PunjabiDB/MeetingWorkBook/*/WatchtowerStudyTheme"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="WatchtowerStudyTheme">
        <xsl:variable name="week" select="name(..)"/>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Some test XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MeetingWorkBook Version="211300">
    <W20191230>
        <WatchtowerStudyTheme>Build Strong Friendships Before the End Comes</WatchtowerStudyTheme>
    </W20191230>
    <W20200106>
        <WatchtowerStudyTheme>How Holy Spirit Helps Us</WatchtowerStudyTheme>
    </W20200106>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

The XML "W" nodes do have more children but I am concentrating on just one of them for the moment.

I can assign each XML file to a variable (`$EnglishDB` and `$PunjabiDB`) and I can isolate all the English themes and display them in a table.

But what I want to do is locate that English theme in the Punjabi database.

So if we are displaying this node for the English file:

```
$EnglishDB/MeetingWorkBook/W20191230/WatchtowerStudyTheme
```

Then I now also want to display:

```
$PunjabiDB/MeetingWorkBook/W20191230/WatchtowerStudyTheme
```

But I can't workout how to build a suitable path into the Punabi database.

Ideally I wanted to loop all the topo level "W" elements in the English file and then locate the match "W" element in the Punjabi file so I could simply display the save nodes of interest side by side in two columns.

But can't work the logic out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this *very* simplified example:

**XML**

```
<anything/>
```

**external.xml**

```
<MeetingWorkBook Version="211300">
    <W20191230>
        <WatchtowerStudyTheme>Build Strong Friendships Before the End Comes</WatchtowerStudyTheme>
    </W20191230>
    <W20200106>
        <WatchtowerStudyTheme>How Holy Spirit Helps Us</WatchtowerStudyTheme>
    </W20200106>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="external-doc" select="document('external.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-name" match="*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="week">W20200106</xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <!-- switch context to external document -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$external-doc">
            <!-- lookup from external document -->
            <xsl:value-of select="key('elem-by-name', $week)/WatchtowerStudyTheme" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version=1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>How Holy Spirit Helps Us</output>
```

Comment: Thanks. It if you were wanting to display both results for the same theme at the same time? Using this approach?

Comment: You never do two things "at the same time". You write to the output the value looked up from one document. Then you create another cell, switch the context to the other document and write the value looked up from there to the output.

Comment: I understand you. I think for my purposes I’ll stick with my method as it is yielding what I need anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `local-name()` and it seems OK now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
      doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
      doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

    <xsl:variable name="EnglishDB" select="document('MWBData_ENG.XML')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="PunjabiDB" select="document('MWBData_PAN.XML')"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <title>Terminology List</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select ="$EnglishDB/MeetingWorkBook/*/WatchtowerStudyTheme"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="WatchtowerStudyTheme">
        <xsl:variable name="week" select="name(..)"/>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$PunjabiDB/MeetingWorkBook/*[local-name() = $week]/WatchtowerStudyTheme"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: (1) If `local-name()` returns a different result from `name()` then the target node is in a namespace - and the proper solution is to declare the same namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use this prefix to address the target node, instead of using a hack like `*[local-name() = ...]`. (2) The preferable way to resolve cross-references is to use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Actually, `local-name` and `name` yeild the same value.

Comment: @michael.hor257k for these keys, is it possible for map the `Wxxxx` objects in each file or does it not work like that? Ultimately I am pulling out matching child node values from each file for the matching weeks.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your solution. In any case, using a key would be better. I am afraid I don't know how to answer your question because I cannot easily reproduce the problem. In general, in XSLT 1.0 you need to switch the context to the target document before using the key.

Comment: @michael.hor257k OK. Don't worry. I used `local-name()` because I tumbled on it in a search. But on inspection they are interchangeable. The XML files in this context are not using namespaces.